# Music bot crash for no reason

Tags: java, hosting, discord-jda

I created a music bot on Intellij, with apache following a tutorial using lavaplayer dependencies.
The bot works, but some times when I use the /play command it connects and a few seconds later it exits the voice channel.
The code of bot work, but some time i have this problem for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get started it with Heroku, it is easy to get started with it. also you can deploy it to Ec2 instance with Tomcat on AWS.